# Infopath form loses some of its promoted field (existing content type) settings when published to a new site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath

My infopath form which contains many fields, loses some of its promoted field (this content type) settings when published to an existing (empty but sub-classed) content type in a new site collection...If I keep publishing to the original site content type the form was published to, the promoted field settings are retained and the correct content type (a subclassed type by the way) columns are referenced. If I publish to a new site collection content type (most fields inherited from a parent content type) only some of the fields are correctly mapped to the child content type fields; the rest are mapped to duplicate site columns (infopath didn't make the association to the existing content type field even though identical field names).

Why are original site collection field (site column) mappings preserved and not transferred to a new site collection like you would expect ?  Is there a workaround that I could do to publish the form content type (preserving the parent child content type structure)  ?

Any advice greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was really a side effect of having published the base content type form which had some corrupt internal field mappings... some   fields containing missing columnids   (see article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deviations/archive/2010/06/30/help-infopath-forms-and-moss-2007-get-along.aspx).   Solution was to delete all of these mappings in the (manifest.xsf) and re-publish to a site content type (update existing site content type) which still contained the correct site column guids (promoting each field with 'this content type').  Then do same for child content type forms with shared fields in the parent content type.

Comment: Nice! Make sure to accept the your own answer so others can find it.